# How to make a diagram bigger in Tikzcd?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, diagrams, tikz-cd

I have the following diagram in LaTeX

```
\begin{center}
        \begin{tikzcd}
            \vdots \arrow[d,"\partial_{p+2}^C"] & \vdots \arrow[d,"\partial_{p+2}^D"]\\ 
            C_{p+1} \arrow[d,"\partial_{p+1}^C"] \arrow[r,"G_{p+1}-F_{p+1}"] & D_{p+1} \arrow[d,"\partial_{p+1}^D"]\\
            C_{p} \arrow[ru,"h_p" description] \arrow[r,"G_p-F_p"] \arrow[d,"\partial_p^C"] & D_{p} \arrow[d,"\partial_p^D"]\\
            C_{p-1}\arrow[ru,"h_{p-1}" description]\arrow[r,"G_{p-1}-F_{p-1}"]\arrow[d,"\partial_{p-1}^C"] & D_{p-1}\arrow{d}{\partial_{p-1}^D}\\
            \vdots & \vdots
        \end{tikzcd}
\end{center}
```

[image]

But as you may realize, it is too small to appreciate its details; even some elements overlap. Can we increase the size of the elements of the diagram, or the whole diagram at once? I am absolutely clueless about this. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can increase the `row sep` and `column sep`, using either explicit lengths, or one of the predefined options (see manual), such as `large` or `huge`, used in this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
        \begin{tikzcd}[row sep=large,column sep=huge]
            \vdots \arrow[d,"\partial_{p+2}^C"] & \vdots \arrow[d,"\partial_{p+2}^D"]\\ 
            C_{p+1} \arrow[d,"\partial_{p+1}^C"] \arrow[r,"G_{p+1}-F_{p+1}"] & D_{p+1} \arrow[d,"\partial_{p+1}^D"]\\
            C_{p} \arrow[ru,"h_p" description] \arrow[r,"G_p-F_p"] \arrow[d,"\partial_p^C"] & D_{p} \arrow[d,"\partial_p^D"]\\
            C_{p-1}\arrow[ru,"h_{p-1}" description]\arrow[r,"G_{p-1}-F_{p-1}"]\arrow[d,"\partial_{p-1}^C"] & D_{p-1}\arrow{d}{\partial_{p-1}^D}\\
            \vdots & \vdots
        \end{tikzcd}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: :-)) You beat me for the time....I will delete my answer.